# finding items in a list

Tags: c#, linq

`personList` is an ObservableCollection
It contains a `assignedChores` which is a `List<Chore>`

What I'm "trying" to do is find all the items in person list where `choreId == cObj.choreId` (passed in value).

However none of my statements seem to allow it.  I'm getting the error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<bool>` to 'bool'

```
var choreSearch = from p in personList
                  where p.assignedChores.Select(ac=>ac.choreId == (cObj.choreId))
                  select p;
```

OR

```
var result = personList.Where(pl => pl.assignedChores.Select(ac => ac.choreId == cObj.choreId));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Any` instead of `Select`:

```
var result = personList.Where(pl => pl.assignedChores.Any(ac => ac.choreId == cObj.choreId));
```

Answer (score 0):

try to replace Select with Where

```
pl.assignedChores.Select(ac => ac.choreId == cObj.choreId)
```

returns bool sequence

Use the following

```
pl.assignedChores.Where(ac => ac.choreId == cObj.choreId)
```

Answer (score 0):

I try to correct you:

*However none of my statements seem to allow it. I'm getting the error:*

*Cannot implicitly convert type System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable to 'bool'*

--You needed `.Any()`

```
var choreSearch = from p in personList
                  where p.assignedChores.Select(ac=>ac.choreId == (cObj.choreId).Any())
                  select p;
```

--Like the previous

OR

```
var result = personList.Where(pl => pl.assignedChores.Select(ac => ac.choreId == cObj.choreId).Any());
```